# How to execute asynchronous tasks in order

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, sequence

I'm currently experimenting with asynchronous functions in Javascript and I stumbled upon a case where I wanted to execute a collection of asynchronous functions in the order that they are placed in an array.

I also want the possibility to pass an argument to an asynchronous function or not. With my current [solution](https://codepen.io/grimmbraten/pen/xxdpyWw), the two functions with a passed argument are executed first and at the same time, then the other two functions are executed one after the other.

```
const asyncOne = async (value = "no value passed to async 1") => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(value);
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
};

const asyncTwo = async (value = "no value passed to async 2") => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(value);
      resolve();
    }, 1000);
  });
};

const sequence = async tasks => {
  const resolve = Promise.resolve(null);

  await tasks.reduce(
    (promise, task) =>
      promise.then(() => (typeof task === "function" ? task() : task)),
    resolve
  );
};

(async () => {
  const res = await sequence([asyncOne("first"), asyncTwo, asyncOne, asyncTwo("last")]);
})();
```

Expected output:

```
"first"
"no value passed to async 2"
"no value passed to async 1"
"last"
```

Actual output:

```
"first"
"last"
"no value passed to async 2"
"no value passed to async 1"
```

Comment: You shouldn't be mixing and matching `async` with `new Promise`, to begin with.

Answer (score -1):

As I mentioned in my comment, you should not mix `new Promise` with `async` – there's no need to, and you'll just confuse yourself and any future readers.

Either way, an `async` function will begin to execute synchronously, which is why you see your sequence (both the `first` and `last` timeouts begin at the same moment). To fix this, you'd need to use a function that calls the function that returns a promise, like so:

```
function delay(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

async function asyncOne(value = "async1 default") {
  await delay(1000);
  console.log(value);
}

async function asyncTwo(value = "async2 default") {
  await delay(1000);
  console.log(value);
}

async function sequence(tasks, init = undefined) {
  let value = init;
  for (let task of tasks) {
    if (typeof task === "function") value = await task(value);
    else value = await task;
  }
  return value;
}

(async () => {
  await sequence([
    () => asyncOne("first"),
    asyncTwo,
    asyncOne,
    asyncTwo.bind(this, "last"), // can also use `bind` instead of an anonymous arrow function
  ]);
})();
```

This implementation also lets you chain values from one promise to another, and allows for an initial value to be passed to the first promise-returning function, á la

```
await sequence([asyncTwo], "hello!");
```

Answer (score -1):

`asyncOne("first")` and `asyncTwo("last")` call the functions and execute them immediately, so it prevents you from executing them in order.

Instead, write `asyncOne.bind(this, "first")`, which does not execute the function immediately and allows you to execute it later.

```
(async () => {

    const functions = [
        asyncOne.bind(this,"first"),
        asyncTwo,
        asyncOne,
        asyncTwo.bind(this, "last")
    ];

    for(let f of functions){
        await f()
    }

})();
```

Comment: `for..in` is for iterating over objects. `for..of` is for iterating over arrays or other ordered collections.

Comment: Indeed, typo. Thanks